How to control a USB powered fan from ESP8266 or Raspberry PI
I bought a USB powered desktop mini fan which has a single button to control the fan speed (1, 2, 3, Off). The fan has a rated input of 5V/1Amp and rated power of 1 - 5W.
I am tyring to find out a way to control this fan from a ESP8266 controller (or a Raspberry PI) which is connected to Home Assistant. Based on certain conditions I would like to start the fan or stop it.
The first hurdle I am facing is that I can start the fan only after pressing the button. So even if I am able to stop the fan from the controller, I will not be able to start it unless I physically press the power switch.
It would be of great help if you could give me some ideas on how to tackle this problem. I am attaching a couple of photos of the fan's pcb for your reference. If there is any obvious detail I may have missed, please let me know.

PCB Front View
PCB Back View


Looks baked from the factory to operate like that. See here: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/download/1145044/FUMAN/FM5001H.html If you interface it with an MCU to overcome this, you might as well control it directly with said MCU.

Yup, that makes sense. Will try it out. Thanks @winny
